# Validate the API key and the city name by the API request

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

I created a custom module where in the block I display the weather using data from https://openweathermap.org/

Code of this block:
https://phpsandbox.io/n/sweet-forest-1lew-1wmof

Also I have WeatherForm.php file with the form which adds in a configuration city and an API key for which it is necessary to display weather.

I needed to Add form validation:

1. fields should not be empty
2. City name should not contain numbers

I did it this way:

```
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $pattern = '/[0-9]/';

    if (empty($form_state->getValue('weather_city'))) {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('weather_city', $this->t('Fields should not be empty'));
    }
    if (preg_match($pattern, $form_state->getValue('weather_city'))) {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('weather_city', $this->t('City name should not contain numbers'));
    }
  }
```

But I got these remark after the code review:

> Also, will be good to validate the API key and the city name by the API request.

I found an example of how to implement this:

```
public function validateWeatherData(string $city_name, $api_key):bool {
  try {
    $url = "https://api.openweather.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$city_name&appid=$api_key";
    $response = $this->client->request('GET', $url);
    if ($response->getStatusCode() != 200) {
      throw new \Exception('Failed to retrieve data.');
    }
    $reg_ex = "#^[A-Za-z-]=$#";
    return preg_match($reg_ex, $city_name);
  }
  catch (GuzzleException $e) {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to integrate the example code into my function `validateForm`. What my code should look like so that it also implements validate the API key and the city name by the API request?

All code of my Form:
https://phpsandbox.io/n/spring-mountain-gdnn-emozx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use both, brainstorm with me something along the lines of..

```
function validateWeatherData($city, $apikey) {
  try {
    $url = "https://api.openweather.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$city_name&appid=$api_key"; // Build the URL
    $response = file_get_contents($url); // You can use cURL here as well incase CORS blocks file_get_contents
        return $response; // Return the data from the call made above
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    return $e;
  }
}

 function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $pattern = '/[0-9]/';
    if (empty($form_state->getValue('weather_city'))) {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('weather_city', $this->t('Fields should not be empty'));
          return false; // Failed to validate city, return false go back start again
    }
    if (preg_match($pattern, $form_state->getValue('weather_city'))) {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('weather_city', $this->t('City name should not contain numbers')); 
          return false; // Failed to validate city, return false go back start again
    }
        $apikey = "ABCDEFG"; // API key (can be conditional based on city via CASE/IF when needed)
        $weatherdata = validateWeatherData($form_state->getValue('weather_city'), $apikey); // Validate weather data
        return $weatherdata; // Return validateWeatherData's response or do something else with it
 }
```